# C# Fast load Bitmap into PictureBox

Tags: c#, bitmap, computer-vision, picturebox

I receve Bitmap image from a camera at 30 fps, and I need to display all images in a pictureBox.
The problem is that the PictureBox is very slow!
I have try to implement a custom PictureBox with DoubleBuffer enabled but the problem  is not resolved.
Do you have a custom PictureBox or an user control or a solution that can display the image faster?

Additional information:
The image resolution is 2048x1088 with 256 graylevel (8bit image).
I use AForge.NET for elaborate the images.

Thank you

Comment: PictureBox is doublebuffered by default. Either turn off resizing or find a fast way to do it before displaying the images.

Comment: @TaW I have resize the image to the pictureBox size before display it.
My picture box is 1536x816 px and the SizeMode is set to Normal.

Comment: With SizeMode.Normal the PictureBOx should not add overhead. As Sebastion noted the `PixelFormat` does make a big difference when it comes to displaying bitmap real fast. Make sure to also convert it from the defualt to `32bppPArgb`! Yes it takes time to convert but the time saved on display should be much more..

Comment: @TaW How can I convert my current image 32bppPArgb?

When the image is in the 32bppPArgb pictureBox it is faster?

Comment: This should do both: `Bitmap bmp2 = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, newSize), PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);`

Answer (score 2):

That image gets expensive to draw when it has to be resized to fit the PB's client area. Which is very likely in your case because your images are pretty large. It uses a high-quality bi-cubic filter to make the resized image look good. That's pretty expensive, albeit that the result is good.

To avoid that expense, resize the image yourself before assigning it to the Image property. Make it just as large as the PB's ClientSize.

That's going to make a big difference in itself. The next thing you can do is to create the scaled bitmap with the 32bppPArgb pixel format. It's the format that's about 10 times faster then any other because it matches the video adapter on most machines so no pixel format conversions are necessary.

Comment: I have resize the image to the pictureBox size before display it.
My picture box is 1536x816 px and the SizeMode is set to Normal.